# Sql query to select records starting with +

Tags: sql, sql-like

Basically I have a user table where mobile is not stored. I want to run a query to select all records starting with `+91`.

My current query is

Query - `select count(*) from temp_table where cell_phone_no like "+91%";`  Results - `0`

While I know for a fact that there are certain rows with mobile numbers starting with +91.

Comment: Which database are you using?

Comment: ANSI SQL uses double-quotes for delimited identifiers, and single quotes for string literals. E.g. `"column name"` and `'some text'`.

Comment: If we take a SQL Server as an example RDBMS , your code is working fine.

Comment: Are you using MS Access as it's default `LIKE` wildcard is ANSI-89's asterisk and not percent?

Comment: @ahmedabdelqader it won't work at all in T-SQL, unless the user has a column called +91%. It would return an error "invalid column name"

Comment: `where  cell_phone_no >= '+91' and  cell_phone_no < '+92'`

Comment: @ADyson, it is working vis SSMS with single quotes , or keep the double quotes with `set QUOTED_IDENTIFIER  off`

Comment: @ahmedabdelqader I'm well aware it will work with single quotes, but that's not what the OP is doing.

Comment: We still don't know if OP is using SQL Server, Access or something completely different.

Answer (score 1):

**Important:** you must to know us your DBMS, because the sintax can be different, but I try to answer to your question

If you have really these rows (the row as `+ 91` is not good), your query can be re-write in this way:

```
select count(*) from temp_table where cell_phone_no like '+91%'
```

So, I've changed the `"` with a single quote `'`

Answer (score 0):

You should check for other hidden values.  I might suggest starting with this:

```
select cell_phone
from temp_table
where cell_phone_no like '%+%91%'
```

This should get any number that has a `+` and a `91` in it somewhere.  If you get rows from this query, you need to investigate why yours doesn't work.